# Finding string in a specific format

Tags: vba, outlook

I have the below code to "automatically" download Outlook emails to a specific local directory.

I would like to be more specific in regards to the file name for the saved mail.

I need to search the email subject and or body to find a string of text in the format AANNNNNNA, where A is a letter and N is a number. If found use that in place of the subject body in the resultant file name, if none is present use the subject of the email.

I can't figure out how to search for the format above.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub SaveMessageAsMsg()

    Dim oMail As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim objItem As Object
    Dim sPath As String
    Dim dtDate As Date
    Dim sName As String

    For Each objItem In ActiveExplorer.Selection
        If objItem.MessageClass = "IPM.Note" Then

            Set oMail = objItem

            sName = oMail.Subject
            ReplaceCharsForFileName sName, "-"

            dtDate = oMail.ReceivedTime
            sName = Format(dtDate, "yyyymmdd", vbUseSystemDayOfWeek, _
              vbUseSystem) & Format(dtDate, "-hhnnss", _
              vbUseSystemDayOfWeek, vbUseSystem) & "-" & sName & ".msg"

            sPath = "C:\Users\XXXXXX\Desktop\Test\"
            Debug.Print sPath & sName
            oMail.SaveAs sPath & sName, olMSG

        End If
    Next

End Sub

Private Sub ReplaceCharsForFileName(sName As String, sChr As String)
    sName = Replace(sName, "'", sChr)
    sName = Replace(sName, "*", sChr)
    sName = Replace(sName, "/", sChr)
    sName = Replace(sName, "\", sChr)
    sName = Replace(sName, ":", sChr)
    sName = Replace(sName, "?", sChr)
    sName = Replace(sName, Chr(34), sChr)
    sName = Replace(sName, "<", sChr)
    sName = Replace(sName, ">", sChr)
    sName = Replace(sName, "|", sChr)
End Sub
```

Comment: http://analystcave.com/vba-like-operator/   Or you can use a regular expression: http://analystcave.com/excel-regex-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way of doing it by simply parsing the string:

```
Public Function FindCode(sCode As String) As String
  Dim sCheck As String
  Dim nIndex As Integer
  For nIndex = 1 To Len(sCode) - 8
    sCheck = Mid$(sCode, nIndex, 9)
    If IsNumeric(Mid$(sCheck, 3, 6)) And _
      Not IsNumeric(Mid$(sCheck, 1, 2)) And _
      Not IsNumeric(Mid$(sCheck, 9, 1)) Then
        FindCode = sCheck
        Exit Function
    End If
  Next
  FindCode = "[not found]"
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

`Regex` might be an option for you (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-language-quick-reference) but given the simplicity of the search pattern then the `Like` operator seems an obvious choice (https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/Language-Reference-VBA/articles/like-operator).

The only drawback with `Like` is that it doesn't return the location of the match in your search string (it just returns `True` or `False`), so you'd need to iterate your search string in batches of 9 characters to find the match and then return it.

```
Public Sub RunMe()
    Dim str As String
    Dim nme As String


    str = "To whom it may concern, find this: AB123456C. Happy coding, Ambie"
    nme = FindName(str)
    If nme <> "" Then MsgBox nme

End Sub
Private Function FindName(searchText As String) As String
    Const PTRN As String = "[A-Za-z][A-Za-z]######[A-Za-z]"
    Dim txt As String
    Dim i As Long

    If Len(searchText) >= 9 Then
        For i = 1 To Len(searchText) - 9 + 1
            txt = Mid(searchText, i, 9)
            If txt Like PTRN Then
                FindName = txt
                Exit Function
            End If
        Next
    End If

End Function
```